# Map items of collection snapshot in Firebase Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firebase Firestore Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) show how to iterate documents in a collection snapshot with `forEach`:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

I imagined it would support `map` as well, but it doesn't. How can I map the snapshot?

Comment: I feel like they shouldn't have opened this can of worms if they weren't going to support all of the Array.prototype methods

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The answer is:

```
querySnapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {
  # do something
})
```

[The Reference page for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs) reveals the `docs` property on the snapshot.

> **docs** *non-null Array of non-null firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot*
>
> An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot.

Comment: In the [Cloud Firestore querySnapshot documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) , the 'docs' property seems to have become 'documents' .

Comment: @ArseneLupin do `documents` support `.map` or `.forEach`?

Comment: I've used .forEach successfully. Intuition says .map should work on a List<DocumentSnapShot> but I haven't tried

Comment: `.forEach()` will actually return the `DocumentSnapshot`s, whereas `.docs.map()` will only return a `QueryDocumentSnapshot `which you then have to run `get()` on.

Comment: [It _is_ `docs`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html)

Answer (score 11):

```js
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
const querySnapshot = await db.collection("students").get();

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs
querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 10):

Got pretty sick and tired of Firestore returning stuff in their classes or whatever. Here's a helper that if you give it a `db` and `collection` it will return all the records in that collection as a promise that resolves an actual array.

```js
const docsArr = (db, collection) => {
  return db
    .collection(collection)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(x => x.data()))
}

;(async () => {
  const arr = await docsArr(myDb, myCollection)
  console.log(arr)
})()
```

Comment: Awesome helper! I would add id as well `snapshot.docs.map(x => {x.id, ...x.data()})`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example

```
var favEventIds = ["abc", "123"];

const modifiedEvents = eventListSnapshot.docs.map(function (doc) {
    const eventData = doc.data()
    eventData.id = doc.id
    eventData.is_favorite = favEventIds.includes(doc.id)

    return eventData
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a better way to do this by using **map** and get your document id as well is as follows:

start with the object array I wish to update in your constructor:

```js
    this.state = {
                allmystuffData: [
                {id: null,LO_Name: "name", LO_Birthday: {seconds: 0, nanoseconds: 0},    
                LO_Gender: "Gender", LO_Avatar: "https://someimage", LO_Type: "xxxxx"},],
    };
```

and in my function do the following

```js
    const profile = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection("stuff")
        .get()
        .then( async (querySnapshot) => {
            console.log("number of stuff records for ",user.uid," record count is: ", 
            querySnapshot.size);
            const profile = await Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map( async (doc) => {
                const stuffData = doc.data()
                stuffData.id = doc.id
                condole.log("doc.id => ",doc.id)
                return stuffData
        }));
    
        this.setState({allmystuffData: profile});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error getting stuff: ", error);
        })
```

In this example I read all the documents in the collection with querysnapshot the when mapping accross them. the promise.all ensures that all the records are returned before you render it to your screen. I add the document id to the "id" element of each object in the array returned, then I use setstate to replace my state array with the array returned from the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Video_Requests')
  .get()
  .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc){
    print(doc.data());
   });
});
```