# How to break out of the querySnapshot forEach loop method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to break out of a forEach loop. Consider this:

```
db.collection('users').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let data = doc.data()
                if (data.age == 16) {
                    break //this is not working
                }
            })
        }
    }
)
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach) mentions nothing about breaking out the forEach loop

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of using [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach) on QuerySnapshot directly, you could iterate its [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property instead, which is just a plain old javascript array.  Write a `for` loop, which you can `break` as needed:

```
for (var i in querySnapshot.docs) {
    const doc = querySnapshot.docs[i]
    if (make_some_decision_here) {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I was searching for alternative to forEach on querySnapshot and you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

According to here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.

the only stop or break a forEach() loop is to throw an exception
Try these alternatives 
A simple loop
A for...of loop
Array.prototype.every()
Array.prototype.some()
Array.prototype.find()
Array.prototype.findIndex()

Comment: A firebase `querySnapshot` is not an instance of Array.

Comment: if you just read the document you provided, it says -> docs
non-null Array of non-null firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot
An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot, try iterate on that

Comment: Fine then suggest iterating the docs array but the only iterator method for the main object is `forEach` which is an internal method , is not Array.prototype.forEach()

Comment: the callback for forEach takes a non-null firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot which is docs which is an array.

Comment: How does that help...can't break from forEach? You already pointed that out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614055/map-items-of-collection-snapshot-in-firebase-firestore and if you have to use forEach just throw an exception

Answer (score -1):

`.forEach` does not provide a direct mechanism for early exits. Your best bet to achieve this would be to throw an exception:

```
querySnapshot => {
  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {

    try {

      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let data = doc.data()
          if (data.age == 16) {
              // Throw an exception to break. Use a custom exception type to
              // distinguish it from other possible exceptions that could be
              // thrown
              throw EarlyExit; 

          }
      })

    } catch(exception) {

      // If the exception thrown is not our EarlyExit type, then re throw,
      // otherwise resume as if look with terminated
      if(exception !== EarlyExit) {
        throw exception
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the regular for-loop approach to allow for simpler look breaking:

```
for(const doc of querySnapshot) {
      let data = doc.data()
      if (data.age == 16) {
          break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' is not an array type or a string type if using for loop