# Defining asynchrosnous function and using it in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to compile tex files into PFD using data from a firestore database. After completion the script doens't terminate. I found one can use process.exit() to make it quit. However, it terminates the child processes still cimpling the tex files. So, I need an asynchronous function.
The guides I found on how to make them did not particularly help me. I am still very new to javascript and any bloat is still highly confusion to me.

The guides I found on how to make them did not particularly help me. I am still very new to javascript and any bloat is still highly confusion to me.
prepending below mentioned makePDF function with `async` and the call of the function with `await` does not work and is, to my understanding, outdated.
I tried implementing a promise, but don't understand how their syntax works. Does simply appending .then() to the function call in the for loop suffice to make the loop wait for the functions completion?
How do I make this specific asynchronous?
Does it matter that it already uses asynchronous functions in its body?
I understand that a promise is used to return what ever the producer has produced to a consumer. Now, my producer doesn't produce anything to be returned. Does this matter at all?

My function called from the for loop:

```
function makePDF(object){
    let input = fs.readFileSync('main.tex', 'utf8');
    const outNameTex = object.ID + '.tex';
    const outNamePDF = object.ID + '.pdf';

    makeTEX(object, input, outNameTex);

    const infile = fs.createReadStream(outNameTex);
    const outfile = fs.createWriteStream(outNamePDF);
    const pdf = latex(infile);

    pdf.pipe(outfile);
    pdf.on('error', err => console.error(err));
    pdf.on('finish', () => {console.log('PDF generated!')});
}
```

And my function with the loop:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('user');
      db.collection('objects').where('printed', '==', false).get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.table(doc.data());
          makePDF(doc.data());
          })
          process.exit();
        })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('no user');
    }
});
```

It outputs a table for each document, but no `PDF generated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async/await can be tricky to use with for loops, that is because async functions return a promise... if you convert the async/await syntax to native promise syntax you might figure out what the issue is.

What you want to do is use `Array.map` to map/convert each doc to a promise that resolves once the makePDF is done, then use `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises to resolve..

The solution should look something like this

```js
function makePDF(object){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let input = fs.readFileSync('main.tex', 'utf8');
    const outNameTex = object.ID + '.tex';
    const outNamePDF = object.ID + '.pdf';

    makeTEX(object, input, outNameTex);

    const infile = fs.createReadStream(outNameTex);
    const outfile = fs.createWriteStream(outNamePDF);
    const pdf = latex(infile);

    pdf.pipe(outfile);
    pdf.on('error', reject);
    pdf.on('finish', () => {console.log('PDF generated!'); resolve();});
}
```

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('user');
      db.collection('objects').where('printed', '==', false).get().then((snapshot) => {
        const promiseArr = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          console.table(doc.data());
          return makePDF(doc.data());
          })
          Promise.all(promiseArr)
            .then(() => {
              process.exit();
            })
        })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('no user');
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `snapshot.map` do? It yields an error for me `not a function`

Comment: @Harri I haven't tried this code myself, but it looks like firebase doesn't return a normal JavaScript Array, try snapshot.docs.map instead as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614055/map-items-of-collection-snapshot-in-firebase-firestore .

map is like forEach but it transforms the array into whatever the function returns, in this case a Promise returning a new array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: The map error is resolved, but the PDFs are still not being compiled to completion and `PDF generated` is not being printed.

Comment: I still had a wild `resolve();` on the loose. It works now. Thanks a lot!!