# data from Firebase is loading in the UI but disappearing afterwards

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

I need to create a simple list using all Documents and its contents in a Collection using Firestore, I reach something like this but now my problem is to show this in UI properly, for some reason **the data is loading in the UI but disappearing afterwards**

my configs are set in this fire.js file

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { auth, provider };
export default db;
```

and now I'm trying to extract the list of documents of 'posts' collection as in this file 'pages/Pubs.jsx'. I did an update and finally found a way to greb the data.

```
import db from '../context/fireb'
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { getDocs, collection, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

async function getDocValue() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
  const fix = {}

  querySnapshot.forEach(
    async (docum) => {
      //console.log('doc.id=== ', docum.id)
      const docRef = doc(db, "posts", docum.id);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      //console.log("Document CONTENT: ", docSnap.data());
      fix[docum.id] = docSnap.data()
    }
  )
  
  return fix
}


function Pub() {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState({
    //'NextJS': { title: 'NextJS', message: 'My new framework...' },
    //'PERFEITO': { title: 'PERFEITO', message: 'incrivel conteudo!!' },//....
  });



  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const newPosts = await getDocValue();
      //console.log(newPosts) 
      setPosts(newPosts);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(posts);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        posts ?
          <div>
            {//the data quickly appears but afterwards it disappear
JSON.stringify(posts)
             /* Object.keys(posts).map(key => (
                <div key={key}>
                  <h1>{posts[key].title}</h1>
                  <p>{posts[key].message}</p>
                </div>
              ))*/
            }
          </div>

          : <p>no exist</p>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pub
```

Ok that's what I am trying to do but no success as you can see, this should be easy but even reading the documentation I'm not finding a way to do what I want. I'm using the version "firebase": "^9.15.0". And here I didn't found up to date questions about it.

the firestore structure is [image: firestore structure]

Comment: What is not working here? Also does `import {db} from '../context/fire'` work in case import statement is the issue?

Comment: what is not working is the way to fill-up the hook, for some reason that I don't understand just the last item from document(firestore print) is add to the hook variable 'posts'. The import db works just fine because it is the default export from the fire.js file. do you know hoy can I fill this hook. I'm already looping through the list of document as you can see in the console.log.

Comment: The problem is more with React than firestore, have you tried putting the ```getDocValue ``` function inside the component?

Comment: Yes I try this now Gabriel but same result at all

Comment: Thank you Gabriel you help a lot with this comment. I'm publishing the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a two ways to solve this issue, but the core of the solution is to build the 'const posts ' with the return of an object so this snippet is the main solution

```
// assuming this "posts" is a colletion and db 
// is a getFirestore(firebaseApp)
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
  const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map( (doc) => ({
   id: doc.id,
   ...doc.data(),
  }));
```

it's implicit multiple imports from firebase/firestore here.

the solution for React only is to create a hook to get this data

```
//...inside an component
const [posts, setPosts] = useState({ });

//really don't matter if this function is inside the component or not
async function getDocValue() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
  //THE SOLUTION! return this 'docs'
  //An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot
  //and mapping it inside the const. I guess it should be obvious for me 
  //bcz const are constant values so it shoudn't be changed, 
  //so when creating this constant 
  //it is mandatory to already pass the value that will be inside
  const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map( (doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data(),
  }));

  console.log(posts)
  
  return posts
}

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const newPosts = await getDocValue();
      console.log(newPosts) 
      setPosts(newPosts);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      {
        posts ?
          <div>
            {
              Object.keys(posts).map(key => (
                <div key={key}>
                  <h1>{posts[key].title}</h1>
                  <p>{posts[key].message}</p>
                </div>
              )) 
            }
          </div>

          : <p>no exist</p>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

but as I'm using Next.js here is a more efficient way to load this data, fixing a bug that make request from firebase ever time this page is loaded using the server side render, it will be load just once per section based on cache

```
import db from '../context/fireb'
import { getDocs, collection,  } from "firebase/firestore";


export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
  const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map( (doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data(),
  }));


  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}

function Pub({posts}) {

  console.log(posts);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        posts ?
          <div>
            {
              Object.keys(posts).map(key => (
                <div key={key}>
                  <h1>{posts[key].title}</h1>
                  <p>{posts[key].message}</p>
                </div>
              )) 
            }
          </div>

          : <p>no exist</p>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pub
```

for those are curious about where I found this snippet it is here [Map items of collection snapshot in Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614055/map-items-of-collection-snapshot-in-firebase-firestore)